# Can Javascript treat Integers as Arrays?

Tags: javascript

I just started learning JS and totally aghast at its type safety. I declared a function:

`function foo(args) { if (args[0] == undefined) { ... } }`

and invoke it as:

`foo(3)`

At runtime, it is happy to index that integer. I was at least expecting that it will not treat '3' as an array at runtime, and say 'cannot index an integer type'. But the predicate gets evaluated.

Is it so liberal or am I missing something concerning JS runtime checks?

Comment: You can access arbitrary props on _anything_, including numerically-named props like array elements.

Comment: and [refer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) for the functionality that you seem to be seeking. you needn't specify a parameter. non-arrow functions (non-lambda syntax) have an `arguments` array as part of the prototype. finally if you want type security, [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in javascript are basically just objects with numeric properties only. As anything in javascript is an object (yes, functions too), you can access properties of anything.

You can do `something.foo`, `something["foo"]` or `something[0]`, regardless of what `something` is. Worst case, you get back `undefined`.

You can also set properties on objects with numeric values:

```
let one = 1;
one.foo = "test";
one[0] = 42;

alert(one.foo);
alert(one[0]);
```

Comment: If you try `undefined.foo` you will get a TypeError

Comment: Fair. Undefined is an exception to "everything is an object" obviously.